# Position of line numbers using algorithm2e and fontenc

Tags: margins, algorithm2e, line-numbering, german

I want to present an algorithm with the package `algorithm2e`. It mostly works fine, only the position of the line numbers are wrong. The numbers are printed within the margin of the page.

I figured out, that it is an interaction with the `fontenc` package. But I need `fontenc` and I am looking for a solution.
In the pictures you can the the problem and how ist should be. Is there a solution?

You find the code below as well as pictures. Because the document's language is German, I need all included packages...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}
I am the text and I decide the width of the page. Nothing should be wider than me, especially not the line numbers. 


   \begin{algorithm}
     \SetAlgoLined
     \KwIn{this text}
     \KwOut{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }

     initialization\;
     \While{not at end of this document}{
       read current section\;
       \eIf{understand}{
         go to next section\;
         current section becomes this one\;
         }{
         go back to the beginning of current section\;
         }
       }
     \caption{How to write algorithm}
   \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This is generated with the code above

[image: Here you see the problem, the numbers should not be printed within the margin]

This is generated with the code above, but with deleted `fontenc` package

[image: This is how it should be, but it is without the fontenc package]

Comment: Note that the answer of the proposed duplicate works, but also in the comments it is noted that loading `fontenc` _after_ `algorithm2e` also works (then you don't need to set the indent manually), which is arguably a better solution than the 'real' answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marijn!